# How to set the core and max of ThreadPoolExecutor in product environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I know the meaning of the core and max of ThreadPoolExecutor.I just want to know how many the core and max is in product environment?

I think the core depends on the threads are CPU-bound or I/O bound.

If the threads are I/O bound, the core can be set Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() ×2 or ×3 or more，because if the threads are I/O bound, the CPU time of a thread get is often waiting.

If the threads are CPU-bound, the core can be set Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() ×1, because the CPU time of a thread get is doing a lot of things, and avoid frequent switching threads to cause performance loss.

But I don't know how to set the max of ThreadPoolExecutor?

I don't know if I understand it correctly.Please give me some advice.

Comment: Depends on the inputs to the application. Sometimes if you have a threadpool to handle remote requests you'll want to set the max higher to accommodate any increase in traffic. If the amount of work is going to be always static, then you can probably get away with setting the core to the same value as the maximum. Again, it all depends on the throughput/inputs of your system.

Comment: Its also a good idea to reserve a single thread for monitoring threadpool health. Every few seconds/minutes log the values of `getPoolSize()` `getActiveCount()` `getQueue().size()` and `getTaskCount()`

Comment: One last comment.. that "× 2 or × 3" really depends on the duration of IO bound operations each thread is going to see. It could be much larger. You'll only find that out by measuring latencies in your system.

Comment: Are you asking 1) how to set `max`, or 2) what value to set it to?

Comment: @flakes Yes, this is a good idea to log the values.And I'd like to know if I understand how to set `core` correctly.